# Can I see Uranus and Neptune with a household telescope?

Tags: amateur-observing

Can I see Uranus and Neptune with an iOptron telescope with a 600mm focal length. If so, can I expect to see them in colour, or simply as white objects?

Comment: Could you provide some detail on what you mean by "household telescope"?

Comment: ioptron 600mm focal length.

Comment: Is that the refractor with 50 mm aperture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I use a Newtonian reflector, 200mm objective, 1000mm focal length.

Uranus is sometimes right on the fringe of naked eye but looks a lot clearer as a small but recognisable blueish disc.

Neptune, sadly, just looks like a star to me ... but you can find it.

Comment: Personally never seen Neptune with a smallish (150mm) reflector, but have seen Uranus

Comment: It also matters where you are (elevation and light pollution) and how good your eyesight is.

Comment: Of course "seeing" isn't enough - I think you also have to be able to say that you identified the particular point of light as your target. If Neptune is in a region of stars, then which "star" is it is an important question